# Error updating record You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, json

I try to update my table but I give this error please help me

```
function updatePost($id , $title, $content, $date, $groups)
    {
        $connection = mysqli_connect(DataBaseManager::HOST, DataBaseManager::USER, DataBaseManager::PASSWORD, DataBaseManager::DATABASENAME);
        $sqlCommand = "UPDATE posts
          SET title = '$title', content = '$content', date = '$date' , groups = '$groups' 
          WHERE id == 1";
        if ($connection->query($sqlCommand) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
        }

        $connection->close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause has 2 equal signs. Change it to a single equal sign ... also, date is a reserved word so you'll need to wrap it in backticks.

```
$sqlCommand = "UPDATE posts
    SET title = '$title'     , 
         content = '$content',
        `date`   = '$date'   , 
         groups  = '$groups' 
    WHERE id = 1";
```

Comment: thank you but now my if ($connection->query($sqlCommand) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
        }    return nothing ... and table dont update... what do you think about that??

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat your SQL query like a string and concat your variables accordingly:

```
"UPDATE posts SET title = '".$title."', content = '".$content."', date = '".$date."' , likes = '".$likes."', groups = '".$groups."' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

Comment: oh thank you its work but now if ($connection->query($sqlCommand) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
        }      return nothing ... and table in data base dont update

Comment: As Dave mentioned above, be sure your WHERE clause only includes a single ‘=‘

Comment: Also, if our answers have been helpful, please upvote and/or accept.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the WHERE clause with the double = is not going to work.